# Sending json object array to .net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I have JSON as such:
EDITED: JSON was wrong. I had typed it by hand

```
var VehiclesData = {
    "VehiclesData": {
        "VehiclesList": [
            { "year": "2010", "make": "honda", "model": "civic" },
          { "year": "2011", "make": "toyota", "model": "corolla" },
          { "year": "2012", "make": "audi", "model": "a4" }]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send this to a .net Web Service API like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ProcessData(VehiclesData VehiclesData)
{
    //...Do stuff here with VehiclesData
}

public class VehiclesData
{
    public List<Vehicle> VehiclesList = new List<Vehicle>();

    public class Vehicle
    {
        private string year = string.Empty;
        private string make = string.Empty;
        private string model = string.Empty;

        public string Year { get { return this.year; } set { this.make = value; } }
        public string Make { get { return this.make; } set { this.make = value; } }
        public string Model { get { return this.model; } set { this.model = value; } }
     }
}
```

I'm getting "Object does not match target type".

With flat JSON objects, I'm getting the data just fine, but with array of objects and a c# List, I'm a little lost.

Comment: your json is not valid http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work as is, I think your JSON object needs to look like this: 
ie:

```
 var VehiclesData = {
    "VehiclesList": 
      [
        { "Year": "2010", "Make": "honda", "Model": "civic" },
        { "Year": "2011", "Make": "toyota", "Model": "corolla" },
        { "Year": "2012", "Make": "audi", "Model": "a4" }
      ]
    };
```

Alternatively, you should be able to use some attributes to help.

```
[DataContract]
public class VehiclesData
{
  [DataMember(Name = "year")]
  public string Year { get; set; }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This will allow you to maintain the lowercase names in your JSON object, but you will still need to remove the "VehiclesData":{ part because I think during serialization .NET will assume that is a property.

Answer (score 1):

I'll mark peinearydevelopment's answer as the correct one for this question. I ended up taking bit of different approach, but all in all very similar to what he said.

I did change the JSON to be one level less (Same as what peinearydevelopment said) so that it only has an array of the Vehicle object and then in the WebMethod I accepted a list of the Vehicle object type:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ProcessData(List<Vehicle> Vehicles)
{
    //.. Do stuff here
}
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps someone else out